# Probability Theory: Regarding the structure of a minimal dependency digraph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, independence

> Deﬁnition: Let $A_1 , A_2 , \ldots, A_n$ be events in a probability space $\Omega$. The ***dependency digraph*** $D$ is a directed graph $D = (V, E)$ on the set of vertices $V = \{1, \ldots, n \}$ (corresponding to $A_1 , A_2, \ldots, A_n$ ) if for each $1 \le i \le n, A_i$ is mutually independent of all events $A_j$ with $\{ A_j : (i, j) \notin E \}$. We say that the dependency digraph $D_{\min}$ is ***minimal***, if $D_{\min}$ is a dependendency graph and deleting an edge from $D_{\min}$ always results in a directed graph, that is no longer a dependency graph.
>
> Show that:
>
> 1. For a given dependency graph $D$ there always exists a minimal dependency graph $D_{\min}$.
> 2. Every vertex $i$ of $D_{\min}$ is either isolated, i.e. there is no edge of the form $(i,j)$ or $(j,i)$; or has at least one outgoing edge, i.e. there is an edge of the form $(i,j)$.
> 3. Either $D_{\min}$ is edgeless or contains a directed cylce (that might consist of only two edges).
>
> Hint: You can use that in any probability space holds:
> If $A$ and $B$ are independent, $B$ and $C$ are independent and $A \cap B$ and $C$ are independent, then $A$ and $B \cap C$ are also independent.

Here is what I got so far:

First of all we note that per Definition $D_{\min}$ does not contain any superfluous edges, meaning that for any edge $(i,j)$ we know that $i$ is dependent on $j$, as otherwise said edge could be deleted,

1. I think this part is trivial, as we can simply start with the complete graph $K_n$, which is obviously a dependency graph, and delete edges so long until we there are no more "superfluous" edges.

For part 2 and 3 I am unsure. I think we should start like this: Suppose that the vertex $i$ is not isolated and has some incoming edge. Then for every vertex $j$ for which an edge of the form $(i,j)$ exists is dependent on $i$.

However, I do not see how to continue from here. Could you please give me a hint?